# How to remove the addtional space between tcolorboxes when using paracol?

Tags: tcolorbox, paracol

When use `paracol` with `tcolorbox`, the gap between tcolorboxes is larger than normal.

[image]

The MWE is

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{.67}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    blanker,
    left=3mm,
    toprule=.3em,
    bottomrule=.3em,
    bottomtitle=.75\baselineskip,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0mm}{teal},
    coltitle=teal}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\switchcolumn
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{paracol}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, I wonder how can I center the example-image-a vertically not only horizontally in the environment paracol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid paracol altogether and use the tcolorbox key `sidebyside`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    blanker,
    left=3mm,
    toprule=.3em,
    bottomrule=.3em,
    bottomtitle=.75\baselineskip,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0mm}{teal},
    coltitle=teal}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common,sidebyside,righthand width=2.5cm]
\lipsum[2]
\tcblower
\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: sidebyside]

Comment: Wow, it's a good idea! Two problems has been solved perfectly! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use `before skip=0pt,after skip=0pt` option for the tcolorbox inside the two column env to eliminate the space before and after tcolorbox. And using `\vfill` before and after the `\includegraphics` command to vertically center the figure.

here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{.67}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  common/.style={
    blanker,
    left=3mm,
    toprule=.3em,
    bottomrule=.3em,
    bottomtitle=.75\baselineskip,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{0mm}{teal},
    coltitle=teal}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[common,before skip=0pt,after skip=0pt]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\switchcolumn
\centering\vfill
\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image-a.jpg}\vfill
\end{paracol}

\begin{tcolorbox}[common]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]